# Date Comparison in MongoDB with JasperReport

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports

I am stuck on find the right syntax for date in jasper with mongodb. Below is my code which is giving me compile time exception.

```
<![CDATA[{
collectionName:"smartphone",
findQuery : {
        Launch:{'$lt' : new Date("24 Apr,2013")}
}]]>
```

in document date is like  `"Launch" : ISODate("2013-09-03T18:30:00.000Z"),`

Exception is :

```
Error Message

com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: { collectionName:'smartphone', findQuery : { Launch:{'$lt' : new Date('24 Apr,2013')} } ^
Error Trace

com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: { collectionName:'smartphone', findQuery : { Launch:{'$lt' : new Date('24 Apr,2013')} } ^ at     
com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.read(JSON.java:455) at 
com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:344) at 
com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:414) at 
com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:378) at 
com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:414) at
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: On JasperSever its : com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException

Comment: I don't really understand the syntax of Jasper, but if it needs to be valid JSON -- I'm not sure how to represent that. You can't create a Date instance in JSON.

Comment: Officially, valid JSON uses double quotes rather than single quotes. The mongoshell accepts both, but the java parser might be more pedantic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to be able to do

```
Launch:{'$lt' : new Date("24 Apr,2013")}
```

Does this work instead?

```
Launch:{'$lt' : { "$date" : "2013-04-24T00:00:00.000Z" } }
```